# Getting blocks of data from Google Reader API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-reader

I have built a basic app using the Reader API but I dont want to retrieve all the items at once to save on bandwidth and processing. I start with the first 50, using

`http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list?n=50&xt=user/-/state/com.google/read&r=n`

but then I want to get the next 50 once they request it.

I have been playing with tracking the `<entry gr:crawl-timestamp-msec="">` but I reckon there's a simpler solution.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've found the answer myself

use the value `<gr:continuation>CArhxxjRmNsC</gr:continuation>`

like `http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list?c=CArhxxjRmNsC`

for more info read the top answer here [How to skip known entries when syncing with Google Reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384771/how-to-skip-known-entries-when-syncing-with-google-reader)