# Google Reader API choose to get only elements from x position to n position

Tags: google-api, google-reader

I use this request

```
http://www.google.com/reader/atom/%@?trans=true&n=20
```

Note: %@ is the URL of a feed source

to get the first 20 entries from that source (%@).
My question is this... is it possible to get only feeds from 10 to 20 for example?
If it is possible which is the query?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism for using offsets (10 to 20 in your example) in Google Reader feed response. Instead you'll need to use continuation tokens as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384771/how-to-skip-known-entries-when-syncing-with-google-reader/1023109#1023109).